# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>' Using DataSnapshot to get data from my models

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

**I am getting error with the _getUserDetails() async METHOD ON LINE
userProfile = UserProfileBrowse.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value));**

**This is my Data model**

[My Data model class where I am using Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQQE1.png)

**Picture of my error**

Error is in the title

[Error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cJhp.png)

HERE IS THE VIDEO I AM FOLLOWING
[Youtube video of the coing](https://youtu.be/aSFCh50cR4A)

**HERE IS THE CODE OF MY PAGE**

```
    class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
      User? user;
      UserProfileBrowse? userProfile;
      DatabaseReference? userRef;
    
      File? imageFile;
      bool showLocalFile = false;
    
    
      _getUserDetails() async {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = (await userRef!.once()) as DataSnapshot;

         //ERROR IS HERE
        userProfile = UserProfileBrowse.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value));
    
        setState(() {});
      }
    
      _pickImageFromGallery() async {
    
        XFile? xFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
        if( xFile == null ) return;
    
        final tempImage = File(xFile.path);
    
        imageFile = tempImage;
        showLocalFile = true;
        setState(() {
    
        });
    
        // upload to firebase storage
    
        try{
          var fileName = userProfile!.email + '.jpg';
    
          UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('profile_images').child(fileName).putFile(imageFile!);
    
          TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    
          String profileImageUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    
          print(profileImageUrl);
    
    
        } catch( e ){
    
    
          print(e.toString());
        }
    
    
      }
    
      _pickImageFromCamera() async {
        XFile? xFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
        if( xFile == null ) return;
    
        final tempImage = File(xFile.path);
    
        imageFile = tempImage;
        showLocalFile = true;
        setState(() {
    
        });
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        if (user != null) {
          userRef =
              FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('userProfileBrowse').child(user!.uid);
        }
    
        _getUserDetails();

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refrain from using screenshots of relevant portions of your code in question. Your data model code should just be embedded into your post just like your other code.

Assuming your data returns in the form of a `Map`, you should be able to omit the `.from` function and just cast `snapshot.value` to a `Map` and pass it directly to your `fromMap` function.

```
userProfile =
        UserProfileBrowse.fromMap(snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

That will definitely get rid of the compiler error but depending on how your data is structured you may get a run time error.